# How to mock fastify plugin?

Tags: typescript, tap

I am facing an issue while mocking plugins used for fastify server.

```
fastify.register(AutoLoad, {
dir: path.join(__dirname, 'routes'))
})
```

Without the routes plugin, I am able to mock routes but when a plugin is registered, I am not able to mock
If anyone has a solution please post it.
Thanks